# unable to attach csv file to mailcomposer in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Hi all i have a problem with attaching csv file mail composer .its working fine if taht file open neo office in PC,but not opening properly if open in iPhone or iPad..
        I am attaching images

if i open in my PC its opening properly like below

[image: if i open in my PC its opening properly like below]

if i open in iPhone or iPad it  opening like below

[image: if i open in iPhone or iPad it opening like below]

can any one help me out

Comment: please help guys narayana is so upset

Comment: What delimiters are you using for separating cells and new lines?

Comment: The two screenshots are for different files. Do all of your CSV files you attempt to open on the iPad exhibit this behavior, or just the files that have semi-colons separating fields instead of commas?

Comment: i am using ";" semi colon as a separator

Comment: Please have a look on this link, may be this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775022/cant-sent-csv-file-attachment-with-mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use This One it may be help you
str_mail = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ :;%@ ;" " ;" " ;\n%@ :;%@;" " ;" " ;\n%@ :;%@;" " ;" " ;\n%@ :;%@;" " ;" " ;\n%@ :;%@;" " ;" " ;\n%@ :;%@ %@;" " ;" " ;\n",your variable];
```